# Replacing dots with a string "ThisIsADot", then replacing again with a dot - does this have any real use?

Tags: powershell

I've been refactoring a lot of our old scripts in our company, and one script consistently replaces dots with a string, then replaces that string with dots, and I simply cannot fathom the reasoning behind it.

Since the author of this script is no longer with the company, and I can't determine why it was done, I would like to remove this code.

Is there any reason for keeping it that I am missing?

Example:

```
$strDotReplacement = "ThisIsADot"

$strAlias = ""
$strRawAlias = ("%param-Alias%" -replace '\.',$strDotReplacement) -replace '[\W]',''
$strAlias = ($strRawAlias -replace $strDotReplacement,'.').toLower()
```

The `%param-Alias%` is an Adaxes parameter - Typically this string would look like: "name.lastname"

Comment: Consider [the principle of Chesterton's fence](https://abovethelaw.com/2014/01/the-fallacy-of-chestertons-fence/). I recommend trying to run this script with input that has various types of valid dot-based input you might expect, and then run a copy of the script with this code removed, with the same dot input, and compare the two outcomes. If there is no impact for downstream uses for your test scenarios between the two outputs, you may consider removing it, as the reason for its inclusion at the time may not be valid anymore. But never remove code just because you don't know why it exists.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you Tyler - It is a very good point you bring up. I was too concerned with whether I could remove something that looked weird, to me, that I completely neglected to try different inputs to see how it worked with, and without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Converting this solution from a comment to an answer:</sub>

> Looks like they were trying to remove all “non-word characters” (which includes “.”) but preserve “.”. - a (slightly) less convoluted approach might have been `$strAlias = … -replace '[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}\.]', ''` given that `\W` is equivalent to `[^\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#non-word-character-w - it would definitely deserve a comment explaining what it’s trying to do though...
>
> – [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) - [2023-02-22 13:25:59Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532602/replacing-dots-with-a-string-thisisadot-then-replacing-again-with-a-dot-doe#comment133264765_75532602)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Converting this solution from a comment to an answer:</sub>

> Apparently your ex colleague did this to preserve the dot. `-replace '\W'` will otherwise also destroy that too: *`\W`: replace any character that is NOT a 'word character' (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)*
>
> – [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) - [2023-02-22 12:58:22Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532602/replacing-dots-with-a-string-thisisadot-then-replacing-again-with-a-dot-doe#comment133264194_75532602)